# JQuery: Can I apply action on all selectors when using event delegation?

Tags: jquery, selector, delegation

I have two UL's such as below

```
<ul id="ul_one">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li class="active">list item</li>
</ul>
<ul id="ul_two">
    <li>list item</li>
    <li>list item</li>
    <li class="active">list item</li>
</ul>
```

What I would like to do is first remove the 'active' class from `<li>`'s in BOTH `<ul>`'s and then apply the 'active' class to just the clicked item. For example

```
$('#ul_one, #ul_two').on('click', 'li', function(e)
{
    var clicked = e.target;
    $('#ul_one, #ul_two').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(clicked).addClass('active');
});
```

Given the fact I am using delegation, is there a way I can remove the class from both `<ul>`'s without referencing them by name again. So instead of saying:

```
$('#ul_one, #ul_two').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
```

can I say something like:

```
$('ALL items in the original selector').find('li').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: Just targeting `li.active` wouldn't be enough in your use case? E.g: https://jsfiddle.net/avs19ajk/

Comment: No, this was a simplified example. In reality, there will be several other ul's with active li's that I don't want this function to touch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing is to cache the ULs.

```
var uls = $('#ul_one, #ul_two');
uls.on('click', 'li', function() {
    uls.find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Very simple. Thanks